# Docusign: How to Bulk send and sign on website

Tags: javascript, node.js, postman, docusignapi, docusign-sdk

We want to send out bulk emails to some our of clients. The plan is

1. Create (not send) bulk envelopes
2. Get the envelope IDs
3. Send the envelope IDs as a request to the eSignature API's "Recipient View" endpoint to create unique URL
4. On our micro-site we have a button which when clicked opens a modal with the document to be signed (Or happy to redirect to docusign)
5. Send out the bulk envelopes

Things to consider

1. Each document might have slight differences, such as renewal price.
2. We ideally want to upload the bulk emails via the UI

Is the above possible and if not could you suggest an alternative way? Could you point me to the specific API requests I would need to make?

```
{{baseUrl}}/v2.1/accounts/{{accountId}}/bulk_send_lists/{{bulkSendListId}}/send
```

response

```
{
    "envelopeOrTemplateId": "123456-f900-1234-b07b-bc2146f87741",
    "batchId": "2d3d3a2d-1234-4cb9-b95686-67890-876",
    "batchName": "Tester Template",
    "batchSize": "2",
    "totalQueued": "2",
    "queueLimit": "2000"
}
```

I am not sure how to use the above response to then complete the rest of the above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bulk send feature is for envelopes with "remote" signers. (Signers notified by email )

In your case, when the signer presses the `sign` button on your site:

1. Create the envelope (using jwt to impersonate the sender). As you say, the envelope's amounts/ data is personalized for the signer
2. Create the recipient view for the signing ceremony
3. Redirect the signer's browser to the signing ceremony

There's no need and no advantage to using batch send. If the content of the envelopes vary, then have your business person ( the person creating the envelopes) modify a template that your app will use to create the envelopes.

If you need to enable the business person to have two different envelopes in flight to the list of people at the same time then you'll need to create your own tracking database for that.

### Thousands of envelopes don't need bulk send?

If you're sending many envelopes that all use the same template with the same documents, etc, then Bulk Send [docs](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=wtn1643071711000&topicId=kjz1578456386508.html&_LANG=enus), [API docs](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/esign101/concepts/envelopes/bulk-send/) should always be considered first.

In this case, the OP use case includes signing via an embedded signing ceremony. That's not supported by Bulk Send. If your use isn't supported by bulk send then you will need to send the envelopes individually. That's supported too.

### Who's clicking my link?

If you're implemented embedded signing via your application, then you need to know who's clicking your application's "Sign" button.

There are several techniques:

- If the person needs to login/authenticate with your application before they can use it, then your app's authentication system will know who the current user is.
- If the signer just shows up at your site, then, depending on the use case, the signer might only need to identify themselves via a form on the website. You can then do whatever level of authentication you want. Eg, the person enters their phone number and you then send them a code via SMS that they need to enter into your app.
- If you want to send the users an invite to your website, then you can personalize the emails that you send out. One email would say to sign, open this link: myapp.mycompany.com/?code=1234-5678-444, another would use the link myapp.mycompany.com/?code=5534-5338-333

  Note that you must not use an easily guessable code nor use an ID since you don't want person A to be able to forge person's B identity.

### Use case: many users, personalized amounts in the envelopes

For your use case, it sounds like bulk send is the right answer except for the issue of embedded signing. You may want to reconsider whether you want embedded signing or not. If the signers are not already regularly visiting your web app, it may be easiest for them to simply sign via an email link rather than signing via your web app.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I need to email thousands of clients though but it's not necessary to use bulk send ?

Comment: Also how will I know which of the thousand senders is clicking the button on my website?

Comment: I've updated my answer. If you have more questions, please open them as **new** questions on StackOverflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We have a Node.js code example showing how to do bulk send.
The example shows 2 signers, but you can do thousands, it will just take longer.
Here is the Node.js code in GitHub - https://github.com/docusign/code-examples-node/blob/master/lib/eSignature/examples/bulkSendEnvelope.js
Here is a details guide with step by step instructions - https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/bulk-send-envelopes/

To get started with working code, use [quickstart](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/quickstart/), which will also do all the necessary configuration for you to run the bulk send code example (and many other examples)